# would've make harder vs would've to make harder

Tags: verbs

I have these two formulations, and I don't know which one is the correct form and why, can you help me with this.

*I could've chosen to speak, but that **would've** make harder the problem.*

vs

*I could've chosen to speak, but that **would've to** make harder the problem.*

Is there a correct form ? or both are valid, if so what's the difference ?

Comment: Check the conjugation of "make" in your sentences. That should help you figure out why neither of the sentences sound right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"...but that would've made the problem harder." It's the past participle "made", not the infinitive "make". (Note the word order.)